# Read and save custom attributes within tags

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I want to parse an XML file with Ruby and Nokogiri that assigns categories to products. The XML file looks like this:

```
<cat-assignment cat-id="123" prod-id="456" />
<cat-assignment cat-id="123" prod-id="789" />
<cat-assignment cat-id="123" prod-id="234" /> 
<cat-assignment cat-id="456" prod-id="123" />
```

and so on.

I want to create an array for each cat-id and store the corresponding prod-ids within this array. Is there any way to do so?

Something like this:

```
parsedXML.each do ...
...
cat_arr = p.xpath("catalog/cat-assignment[@cat-id]")
cat_arr.each do 
  *read all category assignments and create an array for each different cat-id and store the corresponding products within these arrays*
end
end
```

Comment: Can you add some code that you try to do for what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data structure which associates "cat-ids" with an array of "prod-ids" then find all elements with a "cat-id" and append the "prod-id" to the associated array.

For example:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'

xml =<<-__HERE__
  <catalog>
    <cat-assignment cat-id="123" prod-id="456" />
    <cat-assignment cat-id="123" prod-id="789" />
    <cat-assignment cat-id="123" prod-id="234" /> 
    <cat-assignment cat-id="456" prod-id="123" />
  </catalog>
  __HERE__

cat_prods = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Array.new }
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.xpath('//*[@cat-id][@prod-id]').each do |el|
  cat_prods[el['cat-id']] << el['prod-id']
end
cat_prods # => {"123"=>["456", "789", "234"], "456"=>["123"]}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Is it maybe possible to push only the first 10 products per category?

Comment: @Luk579: glad it helped.  Yes, you could do something like `cat_prods[...] << ... if cat_prods[...].size < 10`.